# Simple Silverlight video player which supports smooth streaming and playlist

Tags: silverlight, asp.net-mvc-3, video-streaming

I've been looking around but so far I've the closest I've found which meets these requirements is http://slvideoplayer.codeplex.com/ but it lacks playlist function and as such it becomes useless unless I can find away to get silverlight to work correctly when in tabs on IE.

[Other issue with mentioned silverlight player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734605/silverlight-in-tabs-broken-on-ie)

Although I found a way to trick that player into playing from a playlist it didn't have a playlist feature/interface which means it wouldn't work for normal users since some/many would struggle to figure out how to navigate between all the videos.

Anybody know of a player which is just as simple/near enough which I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [smf.codeplex.com](http://smf.codeplex.com/)? It's pretty simple, comes with excellent documentation and video tutorials, and supports playlists.

Comment: Nope, I'll check out the videos for it  later tonight.

Comment: This has kinda been put on the back-burner as I needed to produce a working project quickly so I ended up sticking to the existing simple player and just making a new page for each new video. So in the mean time I'm gona mark this as correct until I get a chance to come back to it, although I will say at 1st glance this player isn't as simple as the one I linked.